# Get a list of people who are logged in

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cut, tail

I am trying to diplay the firstname and lastname of all the user that a logged in by parsing the output of `finger`. This is what I have tried:

`finger | awk '{$1=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$9=$10=""; print}' | tail -n +2`

Output:

```
Fname Sname 
Fname Sname 
Fname Sname 
Fname Sname 
Fname Sname
```

Is there any way I can get the same output with a tidier command?

Thanks.

All help and comments appreciated

Comment: I'm aware of that command but that doesn't give the output I'm looking for.

Comment: Since you didn't tell us what output you are looking for, how can we help you? You don't want exactly the output you showed in your question with the word Fname redundantly shown on each line do you?

Comment: FYI... We are here to help, not to read your mind or obbey. The chances to get a proper answer are directly proportional to the politeness shown while asking.

Comment: Apologies, maybe it wasn't as clear as I thought it was.

Comment: You didn't tell us what you want. For example, if a user is logged in twice do you want to see their name twice in the output. If a user has 2 login names do you want to see their name twice? Do you want the output sorted? etc... On any system I use, `finger` does not give me output that could be parsed using the awk command you showed to produce a users real name and the full name field from passwd gets truncated at 20 characters. Is that OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
finger | awk 'NR>1{print $2,$3}'
```

This will just print the first name and surname of the users skipping the header. Just print the columns you actually want, don't try and do the inverse.

Comment: It was the awk bit i was struggling with. I only used the tail to get rid of the 1st Line. Cheers.